# Facebook like button not showing faces (thumbnail profile pictures)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

When I paste the link ot the page which contains fb like button here:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/
I can´t see the faces (thumbnail profile pictures) or names of the persons who liked my page.

Can anyone give me some advice how to do the check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like button will only show faces of friends of the current user. If you believe this is in error, file a bug at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs

<sub>There is currently a high priority bug (October 4 at 1:59pm) with the Like button http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/496305530382482?browse=search_50759f368544d5574573563</sub>

Comment: phwd thanks for your reply. That could be the case. I didn't know that the button is only showingfaces of friends of the current user.